# context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null , null ,null, null);

Tags: android

Hi I am working in Android Contact search module.I am running below Query.

```
cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null , null ,null, null);
```

from this  query I am getting Result Multiple times.Is there any thing which I am doing wrong.I want `DISTINCT` Result Set.

please help me.

Comment: what you mean by "Result Multiple times"? Which distinct result set you want. By passing null you are asking for everything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean you got duplicate record for some contacts. So you must add condition for  your query

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection
                        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                        + "=1", null, sortOrder);// this query only return contacts which had phone number and not duplicated
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code will help you

```
public void getContact() {

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

    int size = cur.getCount();
    if (size > 0 && cur != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cur.moveToPosition(i);


            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


            String name = "";

            Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

            if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                                            String id1 = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    Cursor emails = getContentResolver()
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = " + Integer.parseInt(id1),
                                    null, null);
                    emailAddress="";
                    if (emails!=null && emails.getCount() > 0) {
                        emails.moveToFirst();
                        emailAddress = emails
                                .getString(emails
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
                    }
                    emails.close();
                    contact.setEmail(emailAddress);
                    id1 = "";
                    mcontact_arraylist.add(contact);
                }
                phoneCur.close();
            }

        }

        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each record should contain a portion of the data for a contact (eg each phone number or address is a separate row) each row has a mimetype associated with it that is used to determine the data stored in each column. So for an address, the "data1" column holds the street data and data4 might hold the state.