# Display one Contact name with multiple numbers

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am trying to retrieve contacts from my phone that has only numbers and put them into an arrayList, view them in lazy adapter and on click of name I would like show only numbers. I managed to get the list of contacts and numbers but the problem is when I have a contact with multiple numbers it just adds up into the list.

Something like for e.g

David +1 508 656 9043

David +1 403 604 7053

David +1 212 608 7053

Instead I would like to show only David in the list and when I click it should show all the three numbers.

I tried this:

```
  void getContactNumbers()
 {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+ " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, sortOrder);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
     {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) 
        {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              Log.e("contact", "...Contact Name ...." + name);
              if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
               {
                 Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                 new String[]{id}, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                 {
                     String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     Log.e("contact", "...Contact Name ...." + name + "...contact Number..." + phoneNo);
                 }

                 pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this part?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `expandablelistview` is suitable or you must click listview item to open new activity which displays phone number.

Comment: Sure but how to display only one time name for multiple number contacts?

Comment: You can check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13173032/1050058). Add condition `ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP+ " = '"+ ("1")`. If it helps, Upvote or i'll add an answer

Comment: @TheDevMan see my answer and give response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Harshid. There was selection change instead of IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'"; - 
I added HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";

All contacts came up.. Hope the below code helps others!!

Thanks!

```
      final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID
    };

    String selection  = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
    final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,  null, sortOrder);


    if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) 
        {
            String Sid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        Log.e("contact", "...Contact Name ...." + name);
           // get the phone number
            Cursor pCur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     number = pCur.getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
         pCur.close();

    }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to this way query and `get contact` with `multiple number`.

```
final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            final String[] projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI
            };

            String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) 
        {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              Log.e("contact", "...Contact Name ...." + name);
               // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         number = pCur.getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    }
             pCur.close();

        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

Try this code if `getting error` then put comment otherwise enjoy..

Comment: Thanks Harshid quick reply. I am not able to get all the contacts that are available in my contacts.. only few are coming? I changed the IN_VISIBLE_GROUP = 1 to 0, it game me all the contacts names that doesn't have numbers too.